# HTML / CSS not linking?

Tags: html, css

Trying to set up a simple html site with a left aside column but I can't get the CSS to connect with the HTML file, even when the CSS Is written in the file. What's going wrong here?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>My Portfolio Site</title>
  <meta name="description" content="A site built to showcase what I learned in the full stack Udacity course.">
  <style>
    colors {
      background-color: blue;
      display: inline-block;
      width: 30%;
    }
    
    top_header {
      background-color: yellow;
      display: inline-block;
      width: 70%;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <aside class=“colors”>
    <section class=“gray”>gray</section>
    <section class=“black”>black</section>
    <section class=“blue”>blue</section>
  </aside>
  <section class=“top_header”>
    <section id=“logo”>logo</section>
  </section>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: in CSS class start with a dot (`.`) `.colors` , `.top_header`; and keep in mind the space between inline-blocks (they won't stay aligned side by side, use flexbox instead)

Comment: Voting to close as _This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers._

Comment: Use dots before the class names in CSS and *don't*  use typographical quotes anywhere in your code (in your case for the class attributes)

Answer (score 1):

Two issues

`.class {}` begins with a dot

and use normal double quotes, not MS-Word

Please use notepad or textpad or sublime text instead of a word processor

```css
.colors {
  background-color: CornflowerBlue ;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30%;
}

.top_header {
  background-color: yellow;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 70%;
}
.gray { color:#ddd }
.blue { color:blue }
.black { color:black }
```

```html
<aside class="colors">
  <section class="gray">gray</section>
  <section class="black">black</section>
  <section class="blue">blue</section>
</aside>
<section class="top_header">
  <section id="logo">logo</section>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

To indicate a class you must start with a dot

```
<style>
  .colors {
    background-color: blue;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 30%;
  }
  .top_header {
    background-color: yellow;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 70%;
  }
</style>
```